# PHP - Dynamic Pages - Use seperate CSS files for each dynamic page

Tags: php, css, dynamic

Is it possible to call a different css file depending on which dynamic page you're on?

For example if you start at index.php ->
You then click a link that refers to index.php?p=apple

If you have a css file called index.css that is specific to index.php, can you have a css file that overides index.css in the event that index.php?p=apple is opened?

If there is no solution, i may just rewrite my css file to accommodate all the dynamic pages.

**UPDATE: The following is some extract of my code.**

Note: in the something.inc.php page is a link to index.php?p=apple

```
<head>  
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head> 

<?php
$pages_dir = 'pages';

if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
    $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0); 
    unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

    $p = $_GET['p']; 

    if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
        include ($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php'); 
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, page not found'; 
    }

} else {
    include($pages_dir.'/something.inc.php');
}

?>
```

**UPDATE 2: Used the solution marked as answer, and it's all working well. Thanks everyone for the help!**

Comment: Of course it’s possible – but for an average site, I think it might be rather counter-productive, because with a separate CSS resource for each individual page you waste the opportunity of _caching_ your CSS after the first page load …

Comment: Hmmm. By the looks of it, i think i need the link in the head to change depending on what the value p equals. 

Can i use something like this?
if($_GET['p'] == 'apple') { 
echo '<link.....>'; } 
else {.....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url are **index.php?p=apple** or **index.php?p=orange**

Then

```
if($_GET['p'] == 'apple')
{
   echo '<link href="css/apple.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">';
} 
elseif($_GET['p'] == 'orange')
{
   echo '<link href="css/orange.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">';
}
```

If your url are **index.php** or **product.php**

Then

```
$file = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($file == 'index.php')
{
   echo '<link href="css/apple.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">';
} 
elseif($file == 'product.php')
{
   echo '<link href="css/orange.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Tested this out and it worked. Not sure if it's the best way to go, but it works, and that's all i need for now!

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = (isset($_GET['p']))? $_GET['p'] : 'index';
if(file_exists(PATH_TO_CSS_FILES.$link."css")){
  echo "<link src='$link.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
} else {
  echo "<link src='index.css' media='all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
}
```

Comment: -1: `page.php?p='`   will cause error on this page. never trust user input!

Comment: and using `$_GET['p']` without 'isset' will cause `Notice: Undefined index: p`.

Comment: just turn off notices XD fixed answer

Comment: @StefanDunn - If I could downvote a comment I would. Bad advice.

Comment: I've ended up using the solution i marked as answer. Don't know if it's the best solution, but it's definitely working for me. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way i think is that you can generate the CSS link dynamically based on the querystring . You can have separate php file which will act as helper file and you can include in all the pages.

```
         if($_GET['p'] == 'a')
         {
                 echo LINK OF NEW CSS File
         } 
         else
         {
             echo Link of another CSS
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe...

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : false;
if ($page){
    $css = '';
    switch ($page) {
        case 'apple':
        $css = 'apple.css';
        break;
        //other options here
    }
//link to $css
}
```

And remember to use `!important` in all styles aimed to override original.